# How to fix "Cluster must have at least one etcd plane host: failed to connect to the following etcd host(s) [10.xxx.xxx.36]" in Rancher?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, rancher, etcd

When i would like to join a node by selecting etcd, Controle Plane and Worker in rancher UI, i got this error:

Cluster must have at least one etcd plane host: failed to connect to the following etcd host(s) [10.xxx.xxx.36]

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FanKT.png)

So Rancher it could not download the remind docker containers (like etcd, kubectl..) automatically since the docker images should be preceded by the proxy: `<proxy_url>`

- example: `docker pull <proxy_url>/ubuntu` for downloading ubuntu images.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a private registry that Rancher should use to build downstream Kubernetes clusters with by setting the `system-default-registry` parameter in the "Settings" section of the Rancher UI. Then when you launch clusters, it should use this registry to fetch the images. This assumes you have already copied the images needed to this repo ([example of how to do that](https://medium.com/@superseb/how-to-setup-rancher-2-in-an-air-gapped-environment-fd35a0aae792)).

Since you already created this cluster, you'll need to regenerate the `docker run` command and reapply to the node.