# rke up error : FATA[0000] Cluster must have at least one etcd plane host: failed to connect to the following etcd host(s)

Tags: rancher-rke

I am trying to install rke for rancher, then ran:  rke config, that creates the cluster.yml
and  cluster.rkestate,  then ran:  rke up  and got the error:

FATA[0000] Cluster must have at least one etcd plane host: failed to connect to the following etcd host(s) []

how I can fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Cluster must have at least one etcd plane host: failed to connect to the following etcd host(s) \[10.xxx.xxx.36\]" in Rancher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949639/how-to-fix-cluster-must-have-at-least-one-etcd-plane-host-failed-to-connect-to)